# Mongoose save() command issues with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Working with some socket.io code.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema = new Schema({
    user: String,
    chatMessage: String,
    timeStamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  });

var chatMsg = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

  socket.on('new message', (message) => {
    var newMessage = new chatMsg({
      user: socket.user,
      chatMessage: message,
    });

  console.log('at this point of program ' + newMessage);
  console.log(newMessage.user);

  newMessage.save( function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('got here');
    io.emit('sent message', {chatMessage: message, user: socket.user});
  });

// newMessage.save((err) => {
//   console.log('inside newMessage save');
//   if (err) {
//     console.log('hit error block')
//     throw Error('hit error block');
//   } else {
//     console.log('Got to sent message!')
//     io.emit('sent message', {chatMessage: message, user: socket.user});
//   }
// });
});
```

The socket.on section has been lifted from inside the io.on('connection') section for simplicity.
I've also left some commented out code to show my other attempts.

What is the problem here when newMessage.save() is called?
Here is the terminal output I am seeing.

```
Server is up on port 3000
Connected to Mongo server!
a user connected
a user connected
at this point of program { _id: 5b73384a59c100d101bd80f7,
  user: 'jay',
  chatMessage: 'testing',
  timeStamp: 2018-08-14T20:15:06.464Z }
jay
```

The console.log(newMessage.user) is being printed correctly, but something is going wrong after that. I can never get the other console logs that are inside the .save().

EDIT:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.set('port', port);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//MongoDB Server Info
var mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/chatDB";

mongo.connect(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to the MongoDB Chat server');
  } else {
  console.log("Connected to Mongo server!");
  db.close();
  }
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you add the code that connects to the MongoDB server?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Here you go.

Comment: You appear to be closing the connection with `db.close();` as soon as you open it. Try removing that.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for your help. Removing that didn't solve my problem. I was able to continue debugging and by swapping the mongo.connect for the equivalent mongoose.connect did the trick.
I had started with the mongodb methods first and then tried out mongoose...left the connect code by mistake.